# c# 2 BackgroundWorkers started simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Can some have a look and tell me what is wrong with my code?
I'm creating 2 BackgroundWorkers "on the fly" and trying to start them simultoneously. 
The code behind class Listen and Scan is working all fine when executed on its own, but when trying to execute them both the way described below, for some reason they always start one after another.

```
private void btn_Start_BACKWorkers_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string one = tbx_id1.Text;
    string second = tbx_id2.Text;
    string Status = "";
    var bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw1.DoWork += delegate
    {
        string SelectedNumber = "0"; 
        Listen myListen = new Listen(SelectedNumber );
        TOTALlist = myListen.Main();
        lbox_TOTAL.ItemsSource = addIPlist;        
    };

    var bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw2.DoWork += delegate
    {
        Send newScan = new Send(one , second);
        string Status = newScan.hey();
        FinalStatus = Status;

        lbl_SendStatus.Content = FinalStatus ;
    };

    bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
    bw2.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Where is `bw2` declared?

Comment: They will do? Your second background worker starts after the first?

Comment: sorry i forgot to show where bw2 is declared, and YES, bw2 seems to be starting after bw1 is finished.

Comment: Is it perhaps because bw1 is finishing near instantly, so by the time bw2 is called it appears to be sequential? For example if you add a Thread.Sleep(10000) in the bw1 delegate, does bw2 still wait for bw1 before it starts?

Comment: @Ferretallica you shud post your comment as answer nd get pts.

Comment: _"simultoneously"_ is not a obtainable concept when multi-threading.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks **FerretallicA**!
I cannot mark your comment as a best answer so Im writing here:
That was exactly what fixed the problem, BackgroundWorker bw2 was too fast for bw1 so I added sleep time:

```
        bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        bw2.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Now bw1 got enough time to start, before bw2 will start and it's working all fine!
Thanks all You guys! you are awesome!
Simple solutions are the best!

Comment: Are you trying to synchronize these threads? It's a _very Bad Idea(tm)_ to leave `Thread.Sleep` in place for the purpose of thread synchronization. FerretallicA suggested only to add it as a quick diagnostic but it shouldn't be there in any final code. If these are independent operations, it shouldn't matter in which order they start / finish.

Comment: That won't work. You need to add the sleep *inside* the `bw1` code, not between the `RunWorkerAsync` calls.

Comment: Based on this "answer", I can only say the discussion is almost useless. Please simply insert logging code at the beginning and the end of DoWork methods so as to print out the time of start/end. Then you will better see whether the threads under the hood work as you wished.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28VS.100%29.aspx) in the threads waiting for the signal.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing to suggest your code wouldn't work as intended. Is it perhaps because bw1 is finishing near instantly, so by the time bw2 is called it **appears** to be sequential? For example if you add a `Thread.Sleep(10000)` in the bw1 delegate, does bw2 still wait for bw1 before it starts?

For example:

```
bw1.DoWork += delegate { 
    Console.WriteLine("Worker 1 started"); 
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("Worker 1 finished");
};

bw2.DoWork += delegate {
    Console.WriteLine("Worker 2 started"); 
    Console.WriteLine("Worker 2 finished"); 
};

bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
bw2.RunWorkerAsync();
```

should produce:

> Worker 1 started
>
> Worker 2 started
>
> Worker 2 finished
>
> Worker 1 finished

Comment: This is a really poor suggestion as a solution. I could understand this as a quick and dirty diagnostic to confirm if this is the issue but `Thread.Sleep` should not be used for synchronization.

Comment: The question isn't asking for a `solution`, it's asking "Can some have a look and tell me what is wrong with my code?". My answer was presented as a way of confirming what is happening - there is no need for a `solution` where the only problem is misinterpreting the observed behaviour.

Comment: I understood how you meant it (look at my other comment) but the original poster clearly took it as `solution` rather than how you interpret it - read the last line of his answer: he added `Sleep` to time the starting of the second thread. Other (unexperienced) readers in the future will also interpret it that way.